# Query an item in a nested JSON

Tags: json, api, parameters, get

I trying to query a value inside a JSON. I have to send a GET request to an API to retrieve that data using params in the url.

How do I retrieve records which has country = France? What should I add in the query part of the URL to retrieve records that belong to the France country?

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "gender": "female",
            "name": {
                "title": "Ms",
                "first": "Marsha",
                "last": "Jacobs"
            },
            "location": {
                "street": {
                    "number": 673,
                    "name": "White Oak Dr"
                },
                "city": "Saginaw",
                "state": "South Dakota",
                "country": "United States",
                "postcode": 73528,
                "coordinates": {
                    "latitude": "88.6549",
                    "longitude": "58.0396"
                },
                "timezone": {
                    "offset": "-2:00",
                    "description": "Mid-Atlantic"
                }
            },
            "email": "marsha.jacobs@example.com",
            "login": {
                "uuid": "7e61fccb-aa06-48c9-a112-03f2e9860029",
                "username": "bigcat139",
                "password": "batman",
                "salt": "QOayHXLQ",
                "md5": "8ef57655311d2e90092066bc69e054c6",
                "sha1": "f094b59680a5e0377db706c0c3bccb4afd7fe055",
                "sha256": "9d5d62039ccbb59144b1358c65d8a4114a135a80119400f23f2fce4d93713545"
            },
            "dob": {
                "date": "1957-07-26T05:27:00.832Z",
                "age": 64
            },
            "registered": {
                "date": "2019-09-25T12:30:37.247Z",
                "age": 2
            },
            "phone": "(965)-400-1668",
            "cell": "(108)-397-9370",
            "id": {
                "name": "SSN",
                "value": "919-74-7855"
            },
            "picture": {
                "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/17.jpg",
                "medium": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/17.jpg",
                "thumbnail": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/17.jpg"
            },
            "nat": "US"
        }
    ],
    "info": {
        "seed": "a6df1899c0e0a96b",
        "results": 1,
        "page": 1,
        "version": "1.3"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it after a couple of tries! Used "nat" key-value pair to fetch the the desired record!

```
GET {{baseURL}}/api?nat="FR"
```

Comment: what if I wanted to search by postcode?